# Unboxing of 'map.get(key)' may produce 'NullPointerException'

Tags: java, unboxing

This code

```
public static int getValue(int key) {
    return map.get(key);
}

private static Map<Integer, Integer> map;
static {
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1, 1);
    map.put(2, 2);
}
```

produces a `Lint` warning

> Unboxing of 'map.get(key)' may produce 'NullPointerException'

This warning can be fixed by checking for `null`:

```
public static int getValue(int key) {
    Integer n = map.get(key);
    return n != null ? n : -42;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Let `getValue` return an `Integer` instead. But then again, you'd probably get another warning when you're trying to use that return value somewhere else

Comment: This works - and no new warning appears somewhere else.

Comment: This works probably because each method has NonNull annotation by default. When I add Nullable annotation to getValue, the warning appears in the calling method.

Answer (score 6):

As of Java 8, you may use `getOrDefault`, as per the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-

Comment: This will not solve the issue. Even when giving the default value, casting to int will still show the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but as I said here: [Unboxing may produce Null Pointer Exception after checking if key exists in Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69574185/unboxing-may-produce-null-pointer-exception-after-checking-if-key-exists-in-map/78023786#78023786), you have to perform a null check because values explicitly mapped to null are retrieved as null.

Comment: Maybe you can [edit] your answer and post code that demonstrates how to perform this _null check_ - since your other answer does not contain such code either.

Comment: No, the question already has the correct null check. They were asking whether or not there's a better way.