# Unboxing may produce Null Pointer Exception after checking if key exists in Map

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-lint

Android Studio gives the warning: `Unboxing of 'idCollisonMap.get(currentId)' may produce 'NullPointerException'`  even though I am checking if the key exists before I perform the Map.get().

**Am I actually in danger of running into a null pointer exception?  My understanding is that  `.containsKey()` check would prevent this from happening.**

```
Map<String, Integer> idCollisonMap = new HashMap<>();

// All IDs to map
for (MyObject object : objectsWithIdList) {

    // Use the id as the key
    String currentId = object.getId();

    // First check if the ID is null
    if (currentId != null) {
        if (idCollisonMap.containsKey(currentId)) {
            // This ID already exists in the map,  increment value by 1
            idCollisonMap.put(currentId, idCollisonMap.get(currentId) + 1);
        } else {
            // This is a new ID,  create a new entry in the map
            idCollisonMap.put(currentId, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Code snippet sample output:

`[{T143=1, T153=3, T141=1}]`

Comment: Well ... `containsKey` checks whether the _key_ exists (i.e. it is not null). But the `get` method gets you the _value_, which still might be null.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming nothing else is modifying the map, and if the map never contains null values, this looks safe to me - but you can avoid the warning *and* be more efficient at the same time, by unconditionally calling `get` and using the result to handle missing keys as well:

```java
Integer currentCount = idCollisionMap.get(currentId);
Integer newCount = currentCount == null ? 1 : currentCount + 1;
idCollisionMap.put(newCount);
```

Comment: What about getOrDefault(currentId, 1)?

Comment: @pointer: I think you'd need `getOrDefault(currentId, 0)` so that you could unconditionally increment afterwards - but that would work, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I have no reputation, but I would like to comment on Jon Skeet's answer (which probably isn't allowed, but whatever) to make sure that people who look at this question in the future don't make the mistake of using getOrDefault().

```
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 21.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> import java.util.HashMap;

jshell> HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map ==> {}

jshell> map.put("foo", null);
$3 ==> null

jshell> map.getOrDefault("foo", 0);
$4 ==> null

jshell>
```

As you can see, values explictly mapped to null are returned as null by getOrDefault(). To get around this **you have to just use get() and a null check.**